# How to link my Heroku app with my own domain name bought from BigRock

Tags: heroku, dns, nameservers

I have a Heroku app. I want to link my Heroku app, with my own domain name bought from BigRock. I read various tutorials on SO, googled the same, but couldnt find the solution.

In my BigRock account, it asks for **Name Servers**. Under Domain Forwarding, I provided my heroku app URL, but when I try to hit my domain url, it does not serve my page. Instead, it shows a blank page. Although it loads the heroku app url, it does not show my webpage.

How do I link my heroku app to my own domain url?

Answer (score 1):

With in BigRock you have to set up your domain to be forwarded to your heroku app, appname.herokuapp.com and then in your heroku app settings, there is a domain section, that is a list of your sub domains, there you must put your domain name that you bought. You can have infinite subdomains so put yourdomain.com and www.yourdomain.com unless you have a wild card domain then just *.yourdomain.com should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your Bigrock control panel, set the name servers to Bigrock's default:

   ```
   dns1.bigrock.in
   dns2.bigrock.in
   dns3.bigrock.in
   dns4.bigrock.in
   ```
2. Under Manage DNS section, add CName records to point to DNS targets provided by heroku for your custom domain.

P.S.: Don't do domain forwarding as it requires your custom domain to have a static IP address which heroku doesn't provide.

Answer (score -2):

I did and just put the steps here:
http://kanhaiyakumawat.com/blog/heroku-and-bigrock-dns-setup/

## Heroku and Bigrock DNS Setup

#### Sept. 13, 2016, 9:50 a.m. | Tagged under Miscellaneous

For e.g. kanhaiyakumawat.com and kanhaiyakumawat.herokuapp.com

Here are the steps

1. Add records in your heroku account for

   - www.kanhaiyakumawat.com to kanhaiyakumawat.herokuapp.com
   - kanhaiyakumawat.com to kanhaiyakumawat.herokuapp.com
   - *.kanhaiyakumawat.com to kanhaiyakumawat.herokuapp.com
2. So now with this heroku side setup is done. Lets move to bigrock 'DNS Management' section. Click 'Manage DNS'.
3. Add CNAME Records

   - www.kanhaiyakumawat.com to kanhaiyakumawat.herokuapp.com
   - *.kanhaiyakumawat.com to kanhaiyakumawat.herokuapp.com
4. MOST IMPORTANT: Setting up Naked Domain or root domain Setup

   - Now this is most trickiest part. Just leave the 'hostname' text box empty and select 2nd radio button in Values.
   - Put here your heroku dos value

See the picture below